# Jquery Mobile Slider change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, slider

I have a jquery mobile slider on a simple page. When I drag the slider, the value updates as expected in the textbox. I have looked but cannot find where this logic is happening.

What I would like, is to pass the value into a javascript function. How can I bind the change event to my function?

Cheers

Mike.

Code below - please ignore some nasty hacks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery Mobile Docs - Forms</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fader/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fader/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fader/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#slider-1').changed(function () {
                alert("Test");
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .toolbar {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
                padding: 10px;
                height: 45px;
                background: url(fader/Resources/Themes/JQT/img/toolbar.png) #000000 repeat-x;
                position: relative;
            }
            .toolbar > h1 {
                position: absolute;
                overflow: hidden;
                left: 50%;
                top: 10px;
                line-height: 1em;
                margin: 1px 0 0 -75px;
                height: 40px;
                font-size: 20px;
                width: 150px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 -1px 1px;
                text-align: center;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                white-space: nowrap;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .button, .back, .cancel, .add {
                position: absolute;
                overflow: hidden;
                top: 8px;
                right: 10px;
                margin: 0;
                border-width: 0 5px;
                padding: 0 3px;
                width: auto;
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                font-family: inherit;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px -1px 0;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                text-decoration: none;
                white-space: nowrap;
                background: none;
                -webkit-border-image: url(fader/Resources/Themes/JQT/img/button.png) 0 5 0 5;
            }
            body > * {
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1e1f21), to(#272729));
            }
            .back {
                left: 6px;
                right: auto;
                padding: 0;
                max-width: 55px;
                border-width: 0 8px 0 14px;
                -webkit-border-image: url(fader/Resources/Themes/JQT/img/back_button.png) 0 8 0 14;
            }
            .back.active {
                -webkit-border-image: url(Fader%20Test%20-%20Trade%20show/img/back_button_clicked.png) 0 8 0 14;
                color: #aaa;
            }
            h1, h2 {
                font: bold 18px Helvetica;
                text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 0 1px 1px;
                color: #FFF;
                margin: 10px 20px 5px;
            }
            body {
                background: #000;
                color: #ddd;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="ui-body-a" data-role="page">
            <div class="toolbar">
                 <h1>Input</h1>

                 <A class="back" HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)">Home</A

                    ></div>





  <form action="#" method="get">


            <div class="ui-body-a" data-role="fieldcontain">

              <h1>Lighting Intensity</h1>
              <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="a" orientation="vertical" />



            </div>

    </form>

    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Michael. Try to surround the slider with another element:

```
<div id="div-slider">
  <input type="range" id="slider-1" />
</div>
```

And you can get an event on change:

```
$("#div-slider").change(function() {
  var slider_value = $("#slider-1").val();
  // do something..
});
```

Comment: For some reason, the change event binded to the slider wouldn't fire in iOS (worked in desktop webkit, though). Binding the change event to a container element, as suggested above, worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Perhaps a reson to avoid jquery mobile?

Comment: whattt...? avoid jquerymobile... omg i just started it here. @Finnnn ...

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your code is that the javascript binding the event of change to the elements is evaluated **before** they were actually created in the html, thus no element get binded to the change event as you specified.

Try this:

```
$('#slider-1').live('change', function(){
  doYourStuffHere();
});
```

Briefly, live means that JQuery will keep on binding events to elements matching the specified selector even if they were not present at time of evaluating the JS for binding, so this code will bind all present and **future** html elements which match #slider-1 selector with the proper change callback.

Another alternative is to use JQuery 'on' binding which acts little bit differently, but can still do the job. Have a look at the documentation for 'on' [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: live is not a function? why is that.... jquerymobile not support for it?

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest checking out w3schools tutorial on this.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_intro.asp

The crucial piece of code that you are missing is:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#pageone",function(){
    // PLACE ALL YOU EVENTS CODE HERE e.g.
    $( "#slider" ).on( 'slidestop', function( event ) { 
        alert ('hi');  
    });
}
```

Make sure your content is prefixed with:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="content">
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="10" min="0" max="100">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't necessarily need to bind the event inside a pageinit.
just bind it to

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
$( ".mySliders" ).slider({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).bind('change', function () {

        });
    }
});
```

Do not put **`type="range"`** to your input tags, put **`type="text"`** instead.

Since you are calling slider function manually.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation appears to be lacking. After searching for a long time I found that to get the new value in the event handler, something like `$(this).slider().val()` is needed (the extra `slider()` being the part omitted almost everywhere):

```
$("#div-slider").change(function() {
  var slider_value = $(this).slider().val();
  // do something..
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, too many troubles with the event of the slider. Finally I found 'slidestop' event that works great. This is the code:

```
$( "#slider-1").on('slidestop', function( event ) {
   var slider_value=$("#slider-1").slider().val();
   alert('Value: '+slider_value);
});
```

I hope this work for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with jquery mobile, but adding a change handler to the original input element should do:

```
$('#slider-1').change(function(){
    var slider_value = $(this).val()
    console.log(slider_value)
    // do whatever you want with that value...
})
```

Hope this help,

Martin

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for getting back to me. I'm afraid I have already tried something similar to this and it does not work.

Comment: Hi Micahel, I suggest you strip down your code example and let me know exactly what the error is you're getting, and I'll be happy to have another look.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var self = this;
this.sliderTouchUp = function() {
    var currentVal = $('#slider-1').val();
    console.log("val change to " + currentVal);
};
$('.ui-slider').live('mouseup', self.sliderTouchUp);
$('.ui-slider').live('touchend', self.sliderTouchUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest yet and functional.

```
$('body').change(function() {
    var slider_value = $('#slider-1').val();
    if(slider_value == 4000){   
        alert("Holy smoke!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this code and it works in jquery mobile 1.4.3.

```
$(".ui-slider").on('change', function(event) { 
    var valuenow = $(this).find(".ui-slider-handle").attr("aria-valuenow");
    console.log(valuenow);
});
```