# Have two "competing" jquery mobile sliders with the other's value set to 0 if one is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to show a graph of activity on a web site and am giving the user the option to select a date range of either 1-23 hours or 1-15 days. For that, I've created 2 sliders with the help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501536/jquery-mobile-slider-change-event).

So when the user moves one slider, I want to reset the value of the other slider to 0.

HTML:

```
<div id="sld_hours">
  <input type="range" data-theme="a"
    data-hightlight="true" data-popup-enabled="true"
    name="hours" id="hours" value="1" min="0" max="23">
</div>
<div id="sld_days">
  <input type="range" data-theme="a"
    data-hightlight="true" data-popup-enabled="true"
    name="days" id="days" value="0" min="0" max="15">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#sld_hours').change(function(){
  if (0 !== $('#days').val()) {
    $('#days').val(0).slider("refresh"); }
});
$('#sld_days').change(function(){
  if (0 !== $('#hours').val()) {
    $('#hours').val(0).slider("refresh"); }
});
```

If I omit the '.slider("refresh")' part of the code in each function, it works fine, but the value doesn't get updated on the screen so the user doesn't see that the other value has been reset to 0.

With the refresh-method active, I trigger the same change event on the other slider so that both sliders remain on 0 and can't be moved any more.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Correction: the value gets displayed even without the 'slider-refresh', but of course the slider-position will not be changed so value and slider position are showing conflicting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQM slider has a STOP event which triggers after a user finishes interacting with it.  As the user can also directly enter a number in the input at the left of the slider you can handle the blur event too:

```
$( "#hours" ).on( "slidestop blur", function() {
      if (0 !== $('#days').val()) {
        $('#days').val(0).slider("refresh"); 
      }    
});
$( "#days" ).on( "slidestop blur", function() {
    if (0 !== $('#hours').val()) {
        $('#hours').val(0).slider("refresh"); 
    }
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mD6sa/1/)**

Comment: Perfect! That also means I don't need the additional <div>s around the sliders.

Comment: @matthiku this is another solution (http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/E2vv3/) in addition to ezanker's easy one.

Comment: Thanks, @Omar, that is a fantastic solution as well!
Thanks to all the others who have helped me solving this!

Answer (score 0):

Better UI may be to have a single slider:

```
|1---------hours-------23|1----days----15|
```

It'd also make your code much simpler! Internally, you'd have a slider ranging from 1 to 38, with values from 1 to 23 being hours, and 24 to 38 being days (after subtracting 23).

Comment: Interesting approach and a possible solution, but not very user-friendly. The user won't see the proper day values when he is moving the slider (unless I write another JS function to take care of that).

Comment: Well I would assume you already have JS to show the value of the slider, it's really not hard to adapt that into an "hours" section and a "days" section.

Comment: True. I can try that.